# An interface extending multiple interfaces

Tags: java

Below code,

```
interface I3{
    boolean abc();
}; 
interface I2{
    void abc();
};
public class Example1  implements I3, I2{
    @Override
    public void abc() {
        //Eclipse IDE picked this unimplemented method with the compiler error

    }
}
```

Is it the responsibility of a programmer to not get into this situation?

Why Java has allowed an interface extending multiple interfaces? when java has already avoided similar problem of a class inheriting multiple super classes?

In case of similar constants inherited from multiple interfaces, `interfacename.constantname` in a subclass avoids ambiguity.

Comment: The best thing to do is try to compile it for yourself and find out. It will throw an error saying `the return type is incompatible with I3.abc()`

Comment: The two methods have conflicting `return` types, then it will be a compilation error. This is the general rule of `inheritance`, `method overriding`.

Comment: @Satya Definition of override is, *If the  method not inherited is not abstract, then the new declaration is said to override it*. In this case, method `abc` is abstract.

Comment: @overexchange see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801878/implementing-two-interfaces-in-a-class-with-same-method-which-interface-method

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is definely the responsability of the programmer to not get into this situation.

Interface is a way to have multiple inheitence, we must not confuse the JVM with these kind of conflicts.

Comment: Can you tell why you are downvoting the answer? did i said a mistake?

Answer (score -1):

because both `abc()`method have the same signature (return type is not a part of  method signature) and java can't make difference between theme and this situation cause a conflict