# Java sample Output Program

Tags: java

I wrote a program in Java with 2 interface and a class.

Both the interface has the same method name.

In the main class i am implementing both the interfaces and called the method.
I want to know which interface method is called...

Here is the sample code :-

```
public interface A {
    void print();
}

public interface B {        
    void print();
}

public class C implements A, B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            C c = new C();
            c.print();
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("sample");
    }   
}
```

Comment: "*I want to know which interface method is called*" => neither: C's method is called...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing two interfaces in a class with same method. Which interface method is overridden?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801878/implementing-two-interfaces-in-a-class-with-same-method-which-interface-method)

Comment: Actually you don't call a interface method. You implement it and call the method of the class that implement that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interface which is implemented first in a way that interface's method will call and if another interface is next to the first one have same method name that will not going to call at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
public interface A {
    void print();
}

public interface B {
    void print();
}
```

In the above code the interfaces `A` and `B` are abstract interfaces, because some/all methods are declared but not defined.

Hence in your `C` class you are not calling any of these two *(which is straightforward, how would you be able to call a method which was never defined?)*. What you are doing is defining the `print` method (hence giving it a body), to call it afterwards (in `main`).

Comment: @RavishankarChoudhary Please consider accepting an answer.

Comment: Hi there Although i have declare interface and Technology not allowing us to define methods inside interfaces rather it can declare,so two different interfaces may have their own declarative methods  with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You call the class's method

```
 public void print() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("sample");
}
```

Comment: Dear Andrei Amarfii it is not as you are saying it will call firstly implemented interface's method that is A's.

Answer (score 0):

It's `C`'s `print()`. `abstract` methods don't have implementations and are not called per se, it's one of their implementations that's called.

You may want to look into what's called static binding and dynamic binding. In this case to the compiler & runtime everything is at compile time, so the former is employed. Basically it will be statically determined that the method / implementation you want to call is `C`'s `print()`.

Dynamic binding would still mean calling a concrete implementation of a method, so it wouldn't choose an interface method per se, but the choice of which method to call will be done at runtime.