# getDeclaredMethods() in Class class

Tags: java, reflection

```
public Method[] getDeclaredMethods() throws SecurityException
```

has documentation as below.

```
/**
     *
     * Returns an array containing {@code Method} objects reflecting all the
     * declared methods of the class or interface represented by this {@code
     * Class} object, including public, protected, default (package)
     * access, and private methods, but excluding inherited methods.

<p> If this {@code Class} object represents a type that has multiple
             * declared methods with the same name and parameter types, but different
             * return types, then the returned array has a {@code Method} object for
             * each such method.
         *
```

how can a single class have two [declared] methods with different return types, same name and same parameter types?

Comment: isn't that called `overloading` ?

Comment: @Shark To overload the methods must have a different signature.

Comment: You might want to have look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2801878/8116173

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible in the *Java language* to declare two methods with same names and parameter types but different return types.

The Java Virtual Machine (JVM) however has no problem handling methods like that.

There is a way to create such methods implicitly, by overriding a base class method with a more specific return type.

If a base class has a method `Object foo()` and your class overrides it with a method `String foo()` then the `.class` file of your class will have a synthetic (and thus not "visible") method `Object foo()` and a "normal" method `String foo()`. The `Object foo()` method exists for compatibility with classes that want to treat your class as an instance of the base class and don't know about the `String foo()` override.

Additionally some non-Java languages might let you create classes with those kinds of method explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class MultipleMethods implements Callable<String> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(Method m: MultipleMethods.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            System.out.println(m);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String call() {
        return "just an example";
    }
}
```

[Test on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/eg4f1u)

```
public static void MultipleMethods.main(java.lang.String[])
public java.lang.Object MultipleMethods.call() throws java.lang.Exception
public java.lang.String MultipleMethods.call()
```

Due to *type erasure*, the interface `Callable` has a method `java.lang.Object call()` and code trying to invoke that method will look for exactly that method only, therefore, a so-called [*bridge method*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html#bridgeMethods) has been inserted to fulfill the protocol and delegate to the actual implementation method `String call()`. You can identify bridge methods via [`Method.isBridge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#isBridge--).

The same kind of bridge methods are created when using [*covariant return types*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) without Generics, as described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48113777/2711488). Also, as already said by this answer, class files could have been created by other means than Java source code and since the JVM can handle methods only differing in return type, such methods could appear in such classes without having bridge semantics.

By the way, on the bytecode level, even declared fields are distinguished by name *and* type, thus, do not need to have unique names if they differ in type. There is no way to generate class files with declared fields of the same name with Java source code, but, as said, that’s not the only way to create class files.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably confusing `getDeclaredMethod() : Method` vs `getDeclaredMethods() : Method[]` or `privateGetDeclaredMethods() : Method[]`, that have a different name.

However you can have methods with the same name, same return type but different parameters. This is possible because of [method overloading](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/) in Java.

---

For simplicity, this is a very legal piece of code:

```
public class Test {
    public int get(int a) {
        return a;
    }

    public int get() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This isn't:

```
public class Test {
    public int get() {
        return 0;
    }

    public long get() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```