# Why Are Equals and ToString Methods Optional When Implementing an Interface in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I'm fairly new to Java, and I've been exploring the concept of implementing interfaces. It's a common understanding that when you implement an interface, you typically need to provide implementations for all the methods declared in that interface. However, I've encountered a scenario where I declared an interface with three method signatures. Interestingly, two of them are using the same signatures as `equals` and `toString` methods from the `Object` class, and one is a custom method called `compare`.

Here's my question: When I attempted to implement this interface, it appears that I'm only required to implement the compare method, while the equals and toString methods are not `mandatory`. Could someone please clarify why this is the case?

Here is the interface :

```
public interface ICompare {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2);
    public boolean equals(Object obj);
    public String toString();
}
```

and for the code :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     ICompare c = new ICompare() {
         @Override
         public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
             throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
         }
     };
    }
}
```

I get that the Object class already declares the signatures for those two methods. However, what's the benefit of explicitly including their signatures in the interface if we're not compelled to override them?

Comment: It's a language feature, the methods are already implemented so there's no requirement to override them. This other answer about what happens when a class implements two interfaces which have a method with the same signature gives a bit more information and has links to the java language specification: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801878/implementing-two-interfaces-in-a-class-with-same-method-which-interface-method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why Are Object Methods "Optional"?

All classes in Java ultimately inherit from `java.lang.Object`. Any method defined in an interface whose signature matches a method defined by that root class is already implemented. So, from the point of view of the compiler, you don't have to explicitly define an implementation of such methods.

### Why Define Object Methods in an Interface?

To extend the contract. As an example, look at [`java.util.List#equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns `true` if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are *equal*. (Two elements `e1` and `e2` are equal if `Objects.equals(e1, e2)`.) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the `List` interface.

This tells you exactly what it means for any two lists to be equal, *regardless of implementation*. Without this contract, it would be impossible to compare two lists in a consistent manner without forcing the use of a specific list implementation. Note that while the compiler won't force you to override `equals` when implementing `List`, you are logically still required to override it in order to meet the contract of `List`.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, the Object class is implementing those method default so every new instance of class that implements your interface also extends `Object` class, therefore the interface is implemented and there is no need to require special implementation for those methods.

If you want to "force" overriding the default implementation you can use `abstract class` instead of interface, something like:

```java
public abstract class Comparator {
    public abstract int compare(String o1, String o2);

    @Override
    public abstract String toString();

    @Override
    public abstract boolean equals(Object other);
}
```

This will require the classes extending this class to implement `equals` and `toString()` but notice you can extend only one class but many interfaces.

Then the implementation of some class could look like:

```java
public class MyComparator extends Comparator {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are implementing an interface, it is not mandatory to implement an abstract method in your class if there is an implementation(or default method) of a method with the same signature in any of your super classes(super interfaces) (unless there is a conflict). In your case, the definition of `equals` and `toString` is found in the `Object` class which is the default super class. So, that's why you don't need to override them. You can learn more about overriding and hiding in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

But it would be different if it was an Abstract class instead of an interface. For example:

```java
abstract class AbsCompare {
    public abstract int compare(String o1, String o2);
    public abstract boolean equals(Object obj);
    public abstract String toString();
}
```

In this case if you try to extend `AbsCompare` you have to implement all 3 methods. Because there is no definition found in your super class.