# Type 'StoredProcedures' already defines a member called 'AddNumber' with the same parameter types

Tags: c#, sqlclr, database-project

I have created a Visual C# SQL CLR database project. I added two [stored procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure): `test1.cs` and `test2.cs`. I have a function in `test1.cs` as `AddNumber`.

In `test2.cs`, I want to have a function with the same name which will do something else, but this is the error I get after I rebuild it:

> Type 'StoredProcedures' already defines a member called 'AddNumber'
>   with the same parameter types.

The code for **test1** looks like this:

```
public partial class StoredProcedures {
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void test1(string Path) {
        // Put your code here
    }

    private static void AddNumbers(int a, int b) {

    }
};
```

**test 2**

```
public partial class StoredProcedures {
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void test2(string Path) {
        // Put your code here
    }

    private static void AddNumbers(int a, int b) {

    }
};
```

I do not want to change the names as I have multiple other functions with the same name. Also, there are many variables with the same name in both files, too.

Comment: Sorry I did't understand your question  . See it http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Thanks, i have two clr procedures and both of them have same name of function let's say "LogException". Both the clr have this function though they work differently. I am not able to build the solution as it says the above error.

Comment: Similarly i have a some global variable defined in these files, like path, etc. This is alos creating the problems. I have to either rename them or will have to create seperate CLR projects.

Comment: See my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16118110/2218635

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried adding a namespace in one of the file but while deploying i get an error "Incorrect syntax" The code to deploy them in sql server is:
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE ADD_NUMBER ( @Path nvarchar(400) ) AS EXTERNAL NAME Test.StoredProcedures.test1 go

I'm not sure why you removed this bit from your question. If class `StoredProcedures` is in the namespace `Namespace` and in the assembly `Test`, you can use `EXTERNAL NAME Test.[Namespace.StoredProcedures].test1`. The full type name needs to be a single identifier as far as SQL is concerned, and since the full type name includes a dot, it needs to be quoted.

Note that this will cause multiple different types to have the same name `StoredProcedures`. There is no problem with that, but it has the same effect as renaming `StoredProcedures` to separate classes `StoredProcedure1` and `StoredProcedure2`, and renaming is one thing you wanted to avoid (although I do not see why).

Comment: Thank you hvd for the response. I tried your suggestion and still i am not able to deploy the assembly. The error: Incorrect syntax: 'Create Procedure' must be the only statement in the batch. Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, exactly what the error message is telling you: you have other statements than `CREATE PROCEDURE` in the same batch. Or have you perhaps put two `CREATE PROCEDURE` statements in the same batch? Put them in different batches by separating them with `GO`.

Comment: Now the error is : Could not find Type 'Namespace.StoredProcedures' in assembly 'Test'.

Comment: I have no idea how you named your namespace, so I picked `Namespace` as the namespace name. You need to change it to whatever it is you used.

Comment: This is how i have added it in c# code: 
namespace abc
{
    public partial class StoredProcedures
    {
  private const string ERROR_FILE_PATH = "Logs.txt";
}    
public static void test1(string Path)
{
}
}

Test.[abc.StoredProcedures].test1

Comment: Thanks a lot hvd! It worked. Much appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: This is working perfectly, thank you hvd for understanding my question. Love you for this!

Comment: @PeterMortensen I appreciate your attempt to clean up my answer, but the top bit was an exact quote and was marked as a quote, so I don't think changing it is the right thing to do, and the comma you added in my text causes a subtle change in meaning that I do not really agree with. I hope you don't take offence to me reverting it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to interface threw call your class method. It's an easy and structured way.

By implementing the interface explicitly, like this:

```
public interface ITest {
    void Test();
}
public interface ITest2 {
    void Test();
}
public class Dual : ITest, ITest2
{
    void ITest.Test() {
        Console.WriteLine("ITest.Test");
    }
    void ITest2.Test() {
        Console.WriteLine("ITest2.Test");
    }
}
```

Note that the functions are private to the class, so you have to assign an object of that class to a variable defined as that particular interface:

```
var dual = new Dual();
ITest test = dual;
test.Test();
ITest2 test2 = dual;
test2.Test();
```

My answer's starting point is [an answer to Stack Overflow question *Inheritance from multiple interface with the same method name in C#*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2371203/2218635).