# Polymorphism, abstract and interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, polymorphism, abstract-class

This code compiles without an error

```
 class program
{
    interface IA
    {
       void getName(string s);
    }

    interface IB
    {
        void getName(string s);
    }

    interface IC
    {
        void getName(string s);
    }

   public  abstract class AC
    {
        public abstract void getName(string s);
   }

    public class CA : AC , IA, IB, IC
    {
  public override void getName(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        CA ca = new CA();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Which `getName` method is implemented?  If we have a multiple interfaces with the same method name, is it enough to implement just one method that would satisfy all the interfaces?  What if they do different things?  Notice that I didn't specify which `getName` there is (unlike the solution at this [explicit naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371178/inheritance-from-multiple-interfaces-with-the-same-method-name)).

Thanks all.

Comment: The implementation would be used to satisfy the functions in all three interfaces.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Thanks.  If I remove `override` then the compiler complains about the `getName` in abstract method is not not implemented.  So it appears to be a one-way thing.

Comment: @Zuzlx It's different for members declared in an interface and these declared in abstract class. To satisfy an interface you have to implement a method, to satisfy abstract class, you have to override a method. And because you have to explicitly say *my method overrides another one* you have to use `override` modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation would be used to satisfy the functions in all three interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

The method which is being overridden is being called. In order to use the method from the Interface you will have to do something along the line of...

```
((IB).getName(s));
```

You will have to explicitly call these methods.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In your code the method getName in class CA implements all 3 interfaces. If they have a different meaning you would have to use explicit interface implementation:

```
public class CA : AC, IA, IB, IC
{
    public override void getName(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    void IC.getName(string s)
    {
        // Your code
    }

    void IB.getName(string s)
    {
        // Your code
    }

    void IA.getName(string s)
    {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your Class CA,Implements all 3 interfaces and abstract method which is overridden in CA.Since it satisfies all implementation needed for your class CA,It would not throw any error.If you need to call Interface,Call them explicitly.