# How to access inerface method when two interface have same method name?

Tags: c#, interface

I came across very tricky situation about Implementing multiple interface having same Method name as Member.below is sample code for the problem.

```
public interface IBase1
{
    void show();
}
public interface IBase2
{
    void show();
}
public class BaseClass :IBase1, IBase2
{
    void IBase1.show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IBase1.show()");
    }
    void IBase2.show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IBase2.show()");
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseClass obj = new BaseClass();
        //How to access IBase1.show() and IBase2.show()
    }

}
```

Here I have two interface's with member as show() method in each and one class which is implementing this two interface, now my question is how to access this method of `BaseClass` in Main function.

Comment: This is a very basic question, I think if you google this you can easily find the answer. Just cast the object

Comment: @user1845593 it is a basic question, but I disagree that this is easy to google.

Comment: I just google "c# interfaces same method"
2nd result: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31220547/1845593

Comment: Hey @user1845593 thanks for your effort, but some time we didn't able to find solution for easy problem right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cast to the appropriate interface

```
BaseClass obj = new BaseClass();
IBase1 b1 = (IBase1)obj;
b1.show(); // IBase1.show called
// or inline
((IBase1)obj).show();
```

Note, that you dont *need* to cast it, this should be fine

```
IBase1 b1 = obj;
b1.show(); // same as above
```

A nice side effect is that if you have a method where you specify the parameter type then it works fine too

```
public void ExecuteB1Show(IBase1 b1)
{
     b1.show();
}

ExecuteB1Show(obj); // no need to cast, obj is a IBase1
```

Comment: Note that you don't actually need to cast explicitly - `IBase1 b1 = obj;` should be fine. All that's important is that you've got a reference of the right type.

Comment: @Jamiec and JonSkeet thanks, I know this was basic question but I stuck here lol, once again thanks for clearification

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it works with a cast:

```
((IBase1)obj).show();
((IBase2)obj).show();
```