# This is regarding C# interfaces

Tags: c#, interface

What is this piece of code printing "Hi there" as output? And which of the interface's method is getting executed? Please help me understand it's output..

```
interface I1
    {
        void display();
    }

    interface I2
    {
        void display();
    }

    class A : I1, I2
    {
        public void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi there");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();
            a.display();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen when executing that?

Comment: I just want to understand the program flow and execution..I am actually confused.....has display() method been implemented of both the interfaces?

Comment: You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371178/inheritance-from-multiple-interfaces-with-the-same-method-name It explains what you want to understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheritance from multiple interfaces with the same method name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371178/inheritance-from-multiple-interfaces-with-the-same-method-name)

Answer (score 3):

Interfaces do not "execute" they represent a contract that ensures that your object will behave in the same way the Interface advertises.

So in this case.. the class A is able to satisfy both interfaces it implements with a single method since both Interfaces require the same method signature.  Hence, A is an I1 and an I2 ...

```
A a = new A();

I1 i1 = (I1)a;
i1.display();

I2 i2 = (I2)a;
i2.display();
```

Both of these display method invocations still call the one implementation.