# Addressing interface conflicts in F#

Tags: .net, inheritance, f#

I would like to implement the solution described here in F#:
[Inheritance from multiple interfaces with the same method name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371178/inheritance-from-multiple-interfaces-with-the-same-method-name)

Specifically, in F#, how do I address implementing interface functions that share the same name between two interfaces?

Here is the C# solution:

```
public interface ITest {
    void Test();
}
public interface ITest2 {
    void Test();
}
public class Dual : ITest, ITest2
{
    void ITest.Test() {
        Console.WriteLine("ITest.Test");
    }
    void ITest2.Test() {
        Console.WriteLine("ITest2.Test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In F#, interfaces are always implemented explicitly so this isn't even a problem that needs to be solved. This is how you would implement these interfaces whether or not the method names were the same:

```
type ITest =
    abstract member Test : unit -> unit

type ITest2 =
    abstract member Test : unit -> unit

type Dual() =
    interface ITest with
        member __.Test() = Console.WriteLine("ITest.Test")

    interface ITest2 with
        member __.Test() = Console.WriteLine("ITest2.Test")
```

This makes sense when you consider that access of interface methods in F# is also explicit. If you have a `Dual` you can't call the the `Test` method. You must first upcast to either `ITest` or `ITest2`:

```
let func (d:Dual) = d.Test() // Compile error!

let func (d:Dual) =
    (d :> ITest).Test()
    (d :> ITest2).Test()
    // This is fine
```

Note that there is a safe upcast operator `:>` for casting up the object hierarchy in a way that is guaranteed to work at compile time, and cannot result in a run-time exception.

Sometimes this explicit method access is inconvenient, but I believe it leads to a simplification of the type system that makes more type inference possible and increases convenience and safety overall.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It made me realize that my problem is more nuanced because I have a type that inherits from a single abstract interface A, but A implements two abstract interfaces, B and C, both sharing a common method name.  In any case, your solution seems to work for that situation as well, by explicitly implementing the underlying interfaces in my type definition.