# Inheriting multiple Interfaces and implementing methods with similar names at the same time - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, interface, overriding, multiple-inheritance, super

I have the following code -

```
package multipleInterfaceDemo

fun main() {
    println(MyClass(val1 = 1, val2 = 2).myFun())
}

private class MyClass(override val val1: Int, override val val2: Int): MyInterface1, MyInterface2 {
    /*override fun myFun() {
        super<MyInterface1>.myFun()
    }*/

    override fun myFun() {
        super<MyInterface2>.myFun()
    }
}

private interface MyInterface1 {
    val val1: Int
    public fun myFun() {
        println(val1)
    }
}

private interface MyInterface2 {
    val val2: Int
    public fun myFun() {
        println(val2)
    }
}
```

Here I have two `private` `Interfaces` - `MyInterface1` and `MyInterface2`

Each interface has an `Int` `type` `variable` - `val1` and `val2` respectively which are set through `constructors` in implementing `Class`

Both my `Interfaces` have a `method` called `myFun()` which prints out `val1` and `val2` respectively.

Now I have a class `MyClass` that implements `MyInterface1` and `MyInterface2`.

The `Class` has two `constructor` parameters for setting the `variable` values in the two `interfaces` implemented by the `Class`

Now both the `Interfaces` have a `method` having similar name - `myFun()` So there is ambiguity regarding `method` of which `Interface` is being implemented by `overriding`.

Here I clear the ambiguity by calling `super` `method` `myFun()` by using `super` `keyword` and after `super` placing angular brackets and within the brackets mentioning the `super` `Interface` type - `MyInterface1` or `MyInterface2`

Now the problem which arises here is that I can override either the `myFun()` method of `Interface1` or of `Interface2`. But I can't call the myFun() method of both the `Interfaces` at the same time.

So is it possible to do any code tweak so that I can call `myFun()` method of both `Interface1` and `Interface2` at the same time?

A similar C# question already exists -

[Inheritance from multiple interfaces with the same method name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371178/inheritance-from-multiple-interfaces-with-the-same-method-name)

But I am unable to implement the answers in Kotlin

Comment: you can use both `super<MyInterface1>.myFun()` and `super<MyInterface2>.myFun()`  in the same `myFun` function

Comment: @IR42 Got it thank you, do consider putting it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite sure that this is what you need, but you can use both `super<MyInterface1>.myFun()` and `super<MyInterface2>.myFun()` in the same `myFun` function

```
private class MyClass(override val val1: Int, override val val2: Int): MyInterface1, MyInterface2 {
    override fun myFun() {
        super<MyInterface1>.myFun()
        super<MyInterface2>.myFun()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by IR42 is good but the following approach suits me better -

```
class MyClass() {
    class MyInnerClass1(override val val1: Int): MyInterface1 {
        override fun myFun() {
            super<MyInterface1>.myFun()
        }
    }
    class MyInnerClass2(override val val2: Int): MyInterface2 {
        override fun myFun() {
            super<MyInterface2>.myFun()
        }
    }
}
```

Main function from where the two methods are called at the same time -

```
fun main() {
    println(MyClass.MyInnerClass1(val1 = 1).myFun())
    println(MyClass.MyInnerClass2(val2 = 2).myFun())
}
```

Comment: It may well be a solution to your underlying problem, but I'm afraid I can't see how that answers the question you asked, which was how to call the method of both interfaces _at the same time_ — here you're calling them from different classes, implementing different interfaces.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info Your actual problem was something different than what you actually asked for.

Comment: @Tenfour04 well I wanted to be able to call both the interfaces from the main function without the need to comment out one part of the code each time. Also I wanted to keep it organized so that both the interfaces implemented in one class and not separate class. Creating sub class was therefore the optimal solution.