# How to correct CustomList<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, interface

```
class CustomList<T> : IList<T> {
    List<T> StorageList;

    public int Count{ get => StorageList.Count; }
    
    public bool IsReadOnly { get => false; }
    
    public CustomList() {
        StorageList = new List<T>();
    }

    public CustomList(IEnumerable<T> collection) {
        StorageList = new List<T>(collection);
    }

    public CustomList(int capacity) {
        StorageList = new List<T>(capacity);
    }

    public void Add(T item) {
        StorageList.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear() {
        StorageList.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item) {
        return StorageList.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex) {
        StorageList.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public List<T>.Enumerator GetEnumerator() {
        return StorageList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item) {
        return StorageList.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item) {
        StorageList.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item) {
        return StorageList.Remove(item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index) {
        StorageList.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public T this[int index] { 
        get => StorageList[index];
        set => StorageList[index] = value;
    }
}
```

Here my class which implemetns `IList<T>` interface from `System.Collections.Generic`.

This codes causes `CS0738` and according to `CS0738`, I didn't implement `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`.

`'CustomList<T>' does not implement interface member 'IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()'. 'CustomList<T>.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of ' IEnumerator<T>'.`

I can't redefine `GetEnumerator()` because I defined it to implement `IList<T>.GetEnumerator()`. How should I implement `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`?

Comment: google for explicit interface implementation

Comment: You defined `GetEnumerator` to return a `List<T>.Enumerator` rather than an `IEnumerator<T>`. You may have confused this with an explicit interface implementation, but that would be `IList<T>.GetEnumerator()`, not the return type.

Comment: For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation

Comment: You will need to implement both the generic and the non-generic version, and I'd recommend you implement both only explicitly, so `IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() => StorageList.GetEnumerator(); IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => StorageList.GetEnumerator();`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inheritance from multiple interfaces with the same method name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371178/inheritance-from-multiple-interfaces-with-the-same-method-name)

Comment: Hey @JeroenMostert ! I fallowed your advice and it worked. Thanks a lot.